# Mudar src de uma imagem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como trocar o src de uma imagem sendo que ela é passada com uma função php para pegar o diretorio da imagem

Comment: Para mudar a `src` basta `img.src = "nova_src"`, mas sem ver o PHP é dificil ajudar mais. Estás a usar ajax também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, caso você esteja usando o jquery coloque um identificador na tag `img` ai quando precisar fazer a atualização da imagem use o attr do jQuery `$("#id_da_image").attr("src", "novoEndereco");`

> Exemplo prático (jQuery):

```
<!-- incluindo o jquery -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //Criando função para ser acionada no onclick de um button
    var trocaImagem = function () {
         $('#imagem1').attr('src', 'imagem2.jpg');
    };
</script>

<!-- criando tag img com o id imagem1 para ser manipulada pelo jquery -->
<img id="imagem1" src="imagem1.jpg" />

<!-- criando botão para disparar o método javascript trocaImagem para realizar a troca do atributo src -->
<button type="button" onclick="trocaImagem()" />
```

> Exemplo prático (javascript puro):

```
<script>
    //Criando função para ser acionada no onclick de um button
    var trocaImagem = function () {
         document.getElementById('imagem1').src = 'imagem2.jpg';
    };
</script>

<!-- criando tag img com o id imagem1 para ser manipulada pelo javascript -->
<img id="imagem1" src="imagem1.jpg" />

<!-- criando botão para disparar o método javascript trocaImagem para realizar a troca do atributo src -->
<button type="button" onclick="trocaImagem()" />
```